Babel Error: .plugins is not a valid Plugin property When Upgrading to Expo SDK 52
I'm attempting to upgrade my Expo project to SDK version 52, but I'm encountering a persistent Babel error that I can't resolve. Below are the details of my setup, configurations, and the specific errors I'm facing.
Project Configuration
package.json:
{
  "name": "app-mobile",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "npx expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "expo": "~52.0.0",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.2.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^12.1.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "papaparse": "^5.4.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.0",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6",
    "react-native-fingerprint-scanner": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-heroicons": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.17",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^9.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}

babel.config.js:
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ['nativewind/babel'],
  };
};

tailwind.config.js:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", 
    "./screens/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};

postcss.config.js:
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};

index.js:
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import App from './App';

registerRootComponent(App);

App.js:
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import AppNavigation from './navigation/appNavigation';
import { AuthProvider } from './hooks/AuthProvider';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <AuthProvider>
            <AppNavigation />
            <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </AuthProvider>
    );
}

metro.config.js:
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

module.exports = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

Errors Encountered

Babel Error:
ERROR index.js: [BABEL] C:\Users\salva\Desktop\Estia Code\app-mobile\index.js: .plugins is not a valid Plugin property


iOS Bundling Error:
iOS Bundling failed 455ms C:\Users\salva\Desktop\Estia Code\app-mobile\index.js (1 module)
ERROR index.js: [BABEL] C:\Users\salva\Desktop\Estia Code\app-mobile\index.js: .plugins is not a valid Plugin property



Request for Help
Has anyone encountered the .plugins is not a valid Plugin property error when upgrading to Expo SDK 52? If so, how did you resolve it? Any guidance on what might be causing this issue or additional steps I should take would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I solved it by simply following this guide: https://www.nativewind.dev/getting-started/expo-router
